# how to handle multiple return values in scrapy from splash

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen

i'm using scrapy with splash, in my splash i can send multiple values but in my scrapy code i could not handle all.for example, 
this my splash script

```
splash_script = """
    function main(splash)
      local url = splash.args.url
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
        number = 1
      }
    end
    """
```

The method trigger splash from scrapy

```
yield scrapy.Request(
              url= response.urljoin(url),
              callback = self.product_details,
              errback=self.error,
              dont_filter=True,
              meta = {
                'splash':{
                  'endpoint': 'render.html',
                  'cache_args': ['lua_source'],
                  'args' :{
                     'index': index,
                     'http_method':'GET',
                     'lua_source': self.splash_script,
                   }
               }
          },
        )
```

The call back method

```
def product_details(self,response):
    print response.body
```

This method receives only html content, i cant see the *number*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are printing `response.body` . This only includes the html.

You have to use `response.data` to see the 1.

You can also access the elements individually:

```
response.data['html']
```

or

```
response.data['number']
```

And when you return stuff, make sure you are assigning it in the return statement:

NOT-

```
html = splash:html()
number = 1
return {number,html}
```

BUT

```
return {number = 1, html = splash:html()}
```

Basically, you have to assign the JSON keys in the return statement even if you might have done so outside.
Extra info but that really screwed me up and you might run into the same problem.

Comment: What if you are not using scrapy, and data is not an attribute of response?